# Multiple file upload using Request.Files["files"] MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

This is my Code. I want to uplade 3 file into my database

first in View I write this :
<% using (Html.BeginForm(Actionname, Controller, FormMethod.Post, new {enctype="multipart/form-data"})){%> .....
....

and this is 3 file uplaoding:

```
<input type="file" name="files" id="FileUpload1" />
<input type="file" name="files" id="FileUpload2" />
<input type="file" name="files" id="FileUpload3" />
```

In controller I use this code:

```
IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files = Request.Files["files"] as IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase>;
foreach (var file in files)
{
byte[] binaryData = null;
HttpPostedFileBase uploadedFile = file;
if (uploadedFile != null && uploadedFile.ContentLength > 0){
 binaryData = new byte[uploadedFile.ContentLength];
 uploadedFile.InputStream.Read(binaryData, 0,uploadedFile.ContentLength);
}
}
```

but the files always return NULL :(

please help me, thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })) {%>
    <input type="file" name="files" id="FileUpload1" />
    <input type="file" name="files" id="FileUpload2" />
    <input type="file" name="files" id="FileUpload3" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
<% } %>
```

and the corresponding controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
    {
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            if (file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                // TODO: do something with the uploaded file here
            }
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

It's a bit cleaner.

Comment: Is it necessary to add "IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files" to actionResult as parameter? I do that but still NULL

Comment: Yes, this way you no longer need to use the `Request.Files` inside the action. The default model binder will do the job. I don't know why you are getting NULL. Are those inputs inside the form? When I tested my code I was able to fetch the uploaded files.

Comment: What if I'm already getting a model back for the rest of the things on the page as the argument to my controller method, how do I make this work then?

Comment: @JamesBender, you simply define a view model and have your controller action take this view model as parameter.

Answer (score 2):

You should use:

```
IList<HttpPostedFileBase> files = Request.Files.GetMultiple("files")
```

instead.