# Issue in Uploading multiple files using c#

Tags: c#, file, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to upload multiple files, (selecting multiple files in a single click and upload). For that I am using the following code. I am doing this in MVC4

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Gallery", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, new  {enctype="multipart/form-data", id = "GalleryForm" }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary();

    <div> Select the files to Upload<br /> <input type="file" name="file" id="file" multiple="multiple" /><br /><br /></div>
    <div><input type="submit" name="submit" Value="Save"/></div>
}
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Gallery(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
{
    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        if (file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images/Gallery/"), fileName);
            file.SaveAs(path);
         }
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

If I select more than one file, I got the error "Maximum request length exceeded" and when I select single file and try to upload then, I got the error `"Object reference not set to an instance of an object"`. Actually, I want to upload single and multiple files using this same form. How will this be possible. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: More info required:  What line of the code shown is giving the error? It's probably the foreach.. files that is null because the parameter name doesn't match . See also this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356506/how-to-write-html-beginform-in-razor  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4232347/multiple-file-upload-using-request-filesfiles-mvc

Comment: @DaviddCeFreitas: i want to upload more than one file using "Single input control"

Answer (score 1):

Rename your `name` attribute of input type file

```
<input type="file" name="files" id="file" multiple="multiple" />
```

for  second error i.e maximunn length exceed change in web config

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

For IIS7 and above, you also need to add the lines below:

```
<system.webServer>
   <security>
      <requestFiltering>
         <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
      </requestFiltering>
   </security>
 </system.webServer>
```

Note: maxAllowedContentLength is measured in bytes while maxRequestLength is measured in kilobytes, which is why the values differ in this config example. (Both are equivalent to 1 GB.)

Answer (score 0):

Your parameter name doesn't match your form input element name, you should use "file" or "files" in both the code behind and the html.  `name="file"` should be `name="files"`.

Comment: some times i want to upload more than one files using this input control. but this code only allow to upload a single file